# Unable to send mail with excel attachment in c#

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, email, attachment

I am trying to send mail with excel attachment, the mail is getting sent but the attachment is in filename.xlsx.txt with no content (blank .txt file)

```
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.test.net");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
        mail.To.Add("test@test.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
        mail.Body = "mail with attachment";


        Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new Attachment(File.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "result.xlsx", FileMode.Open), "result.xlsx");
        attachment.ContentType = new ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.test.net");
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        NetworkCredential credetial = new NetworkCredential("test@test.com", "******", "test.com");
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Email Attachment:

[image: Email Attachment]

Comment: 306 bytes = no content? What's in those 306 bytes?

Comment: perhaps you should not rename it to .txt

Comment: @ Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen nothing just a blank text file instead of excel with content

Comment: @Alander I am not renaming it to .txt

Comment: your encoding might be wrong, try the answer by flindeberg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223200/how-can-i-send-an-excel-file-by-email

Comment: `message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "result.xlsx")); message.IsBodyHtml = True`.  I have exactly the same code and it works fine.

Comment: @AllenKing tried the code you provided but still the same result

Comment: You should check if the app pool (if IIS) has permissions to read the directory in question

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually attaching the file, instead you are opening the file and saving it as `result.xlsx` and this defaults to `.txt` extension when saved. that explains why you are getting `result.xlsx.txt`

Instead of

```
Attachemnt attachment = new Attachment(File.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "result.xlsx", FileMode.Open), "result.xlsx");
attachment.ContentType = new ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Use

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(PathToAttachment));
```

Just pass the path to the file.

**Again Am not sure you need the content type bit.**

Comment: What do you mean by same result?, Is it `result.xlsx.txt`? Hope you rebuild your code

Comment: Yes, same result.xlsx.txt with no data

Answer (score 0):

I have a spreadsheet I attach like this...
(Using your object name "mail")

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(mail, "result.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"));
```

Instead of:

```
Attachment attachment;
attachment = new Attachment(File.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "result.xlsx", FileMode.Open), "result.xlsx");
attachment.ContentType = new ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: See if you can open the file you created with Excel...maybe your just creating a text file.

Comment: No, that I have checked file I am creating is getting successfully created with proper data but when I am sending it through mail I am getting the above result.xlsx.txt file with no data.